# Protecting against cellForRowatIndexPath passing an index to an array that would be beyond its bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Here is my problem:

Lets say that I have 2 `UITableViewCell` with Label1 and Label2 in each cell. Label1 is going to continuously be receiving a value at each index, so array[0] and array[1] != nil. This is not the case for Label2; Label2 receives a value at its array[0], but array[1] = nil.

Here is the latest method that I have tried, however, it doesn't catch array2 being out of bounds.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

      if (array1.count >= indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        NSString *label1String = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label1 setText:label1String];

    }

    if (array2.count >= indexPath.row){
        UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        NSString *label2String = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [label2 setText:label2String];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array index ranges from `0` to `count-1`, so the check has to be

```
if ( indexPath.row < array2.count )
```

The row is not allowed to be equal to the count.

Comment: @initWithQuestion - you can mark this correct with the little checkmark at the upper left.

Comment: I will as soon as I am able to. There are 5 minutes on the counter :(
I do wonder, does indexPath.row begin at 0, or at 1 as the initial value?

Comment: everything is 0 based